# How to set in JSP page a field with my own value?

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a variable to a servlet with my own value .

Using that :

```
<input type="text" name="usernameNew"><br>
```

I can grab the `usernameNew` in the servlet , but I'd need to let the user put some input into that text-field - and that I don't want .

What I want is to set the value of `usernameNew` to something , in the JSP page , for instance a String with the value `myText`  , without asking the user to put any input (meaning , I want the `usernameNew` to be some kind of a flag , and use that in my servlet for `IF` conditions) .

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [hidden input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#hidden-control).  Either that or add it to a normal field but make it [read-only](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2). That way the user can see, but not change, the data.

And note this this is really about [forms in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

Comment: Okay , and then when I grab the hidden input in the servlet , it would be in the same way I grab a "normal" input ? with `request.getParameter("somethingGoesHere");` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT name=userID size = 20 >  
<jsp:setProperty name="formBean"   
                 property="loginID"   
                 param="userID" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
passing hidden  value

    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="${user.id}">

<%
 String getHiddenValue=request.getParameter("userid");
 System.out.println("Hidden field Value :"+getHiddenValue);
%>
```